# Having trouble with a search and replace using regular exrpession in Rails

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, search, replace

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I am trying got replace a parameter in my URL with the same value but adding “1” to it.  So for instance if my URL is

```
http://replace.mydomein.com/profiles/152/expanded?embed=true&page=2
```

I would want the result after the substitution to be

```
http://replace.mydomein.com/profiles/152/expanded?embed=true&page=3
```

So I’m trying this

```
url = url.sub(/(\&<=page=)\d+/) {|m| m.to_i+1}
```

but it is having no effect on my URL.  Passing “http://replace.mydomein.com/profiles/152/expanded?embed=true&page=2” as an argument yields the same result.  What am I doing wrong in my regular expression above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to replace the `\&` in your regex to `?`

```
url = url.sub(/(?<=page=)\d+/) { |m| m.to_i.next }
```

Because the syntax for a positive lookbehind `(?<=` is like that.